# Azure RBAC for remove access to create new subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I'm trying to remove the permission to the user on my azure tenant to create a new subscription.

The only way a find is the but the GlobalReader role in active directory when I create the user.
But with this method, the user can see the active directory same I block it with users' permission.

I also try to create a rbac in my tenant root in my management group. But when I but a reader role the user can create a new subscription again.

Answer (score 0):

Azure RBAC just for control Azure subscription resource access here, it will not work for  Azure subscription creation.

For creating Azure subscriptions ,based on [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/understand-mca-roles#subscription-billing-roles-and-tasks), only users who have [billing roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/understand-mca-roles#billing-role-definitions):

> Invoice section owner , Invoice section contributor , Azure
>   subscription creator

Will be able to create Azure subscriptions.

Billing roles belongs to your [billing account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/mca-overview#your-billing-account) . [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/view-all-accounts) describes the relationship with billing account with your subscriptions well.

Hope it helps .